# How to Configure Launcher Placement in Multi-monitor Setup

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, launcher

I use a large monitor as primary and laptop screen as secondary. Is it possible to move the launcher to my big monitor or do I have to turn off my laptop monitor?

- "Monitor Preferences" (Launcher search -> "Monitors") does not have a way to set the default/primary monitor.
- `nvidia-settings` which I just installed says "You do not appear to be using the NVDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.

  - `sudo nvidia-xconfig` says `sudo: nvidia-xconfig: command not found`.
- I guess I don't have an AMD driver because I don't have "AMD Catylist Control Center" in the launcher search.

Answer (score 2):

Launcher placement can be achieved via System Settings -> Displays or via command line.

#### GUI way

Under System Settings -> Displays find the Launcher placement option

[image]

#### Command line way

The placement is determined by two things:

1. Which monitor is the primary ?
2. What value is set in `/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/num-launchers` dconf schema.

The `dconf` schema is very easy. Value 1 indicates one launcher, value 2 indicates multiple launchers (i.e., place it on all screens) . You can alter that with

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/num-launchers INT`
```

or

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ num-launchers INT
```

where `INT` is either 0 or 1.

The `xrandr` command will tell you what monitors are connected and what is your current primary screen. It will also allow setting and unsetting that with `--primary` flag.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2390 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1366x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

In the output above I have my external VGA1 screen set as primary , hence launcher will show up there.

For instance, if I wanted to use my build-in monitor as primary, then

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --right-of VGA1
```

And the launcher will jump from left screen ( VGA1 ) to my right screen, while preserving the layout.

For more info, read xrandr and dconf man pages.

Comment: Better suggest `gsettings` rather then writing to `dconf` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The launcher shows up on whichever is your primary/default monitor.  You should be able to configure this in the Monitor settings (click the BFB or press Super, then type in `monitors`).  Or, if your computer has an nvidia driver, you should install `nvidia-settings` and use that.

Comment: How exactly do you make the external monitor the primary monitor?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AMD driver, the following worked for me:

1. `Super`
2. `AMD Catylist Control Center (Administrative)`
3. `Multi Display Options` --> `Single Display (Multi Desktop)`

Comment: @George it AMD Catylist Control Center isn't necessarily installed by default.