# Can I configure the Unity launcher to appear on both of my monitors?

Tags: unity, launcher, multiple-monitors

I would like to have the Unity launcher appear on both of my monitors. If the launchers could be configured to show only the windows active on their respective monitors, that would be even better.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Close as too localized? This is now supported, it's the default behavior.

Comment: I've written a generic answer that addresses launcher placement. Please refer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/766098/295286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to display the launcher on each screen but work is going to be done in the 12.04 cycle to support multi screen usage better:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/742544
- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)

Comment: In a recent poll run through OMGUbuntu the default was decided to use only one launcher. instead of one launcher per monitor. How to change this to launcher on every monitor?